# How to optimize this simple algorithm further?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, c++11, optimization

*Note: this is a programming challenge*

---

This challenge requires usage of `std::set`.

**Input**

- A number `n`
- `n` lines with each `j` and `k`

Sample input:

```
5
1 4
2 1
1 6
3 4
1 2
```

`j` is for the operation: `1` to insert `k`, `2` to delete `k` (if there is a `k`), `3` find `k`

For `j == 3`, output `Yes` or `No` if `k` is in the `std::set`.

---

I made different versions of the algorithm, but all are way too slow. I tried different `std` functions, but `std::find` seems the fastest one, but is still too slow. Implementing my own would be even worse, so maybe I missed a function from the library. I really have no idea how to optimize it further. Currently I have this:

```
int main()
{
    std::set<int> set{};
    int Q = 0;
    std::cin >> Q;

    int type = 0;
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Q; ++i)
    {
        std::cin >> type;
        std::cin >> x;

        if (type == 1)
            set.insert(x);
        else if (type == 2)
            set.erase(x);
        else if (type == 3)
            std::cout << (std::find(std::begin(set), std::end(set), x) != std::end(set) ? "Yes" : "No") << '\n';
            //Condition may be std::find, std::count or std::binary_search
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

The challenge requires it to run under 2 seconds. Here are the results of mine:

```
Function              Time           % over
std::find          -> 7.410s         370.50%
std::count         -> 7.881s         394.05%
std::binary_search -> 14.050s        702.50%
```

As you can see my algorithm is 3x slower than the required algorithm. The bottlenecks are clearly those functions:

```
Function               % of total time 
std::find          ->  77.61%
std::count         ->  80.80%
std::binary_search ->  87.59%
```

But currently I have no better idea than to use `std::find` or similar functions. Does someone have a way/idea to optimize my code further? Or are there some obvious bottlenecks that I'm missing?

Comment: That chain of `if` statements is really crying out for a proper `switch`.

Comment: @tadman thanks, I'll try.

Comment: Did you try `set.find()`?

Comment: @VaughnCato No, but I'll do. Aren't they the same?

Comment: The `find` method associated with a class is usually optimized for the container involved. The generic `find` method is able to operate on anything which can produce an interator but may be slower.

Comment: upvoted for already identifying which part of the program was too slow.  Even though the solution in this case is obvious once you understand it, profiling like this is absolutely the right approach.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Could you edit the approved answer with your new profiling results, just to see the improvement between the usage of either one or the other `find` function?

Comment: @LoPiTaL I'll try to find the code and measure again :) Will take a while though, because that was two years ago for a programming challenge, and I don't keep those programs *normally*. But I don't know. I'll message you when I update my post.

Comment: it is true! Just the question was shown in my "new questions" and though it was recent... don't worry then....

Comment: @LoPiTaL Because I randomly thought of that question and noticed that the answer had a typo, so I fixed it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want to use `set.find()` and not `std::find(set.begin(),set.end())`.

`set.find()` will use the set's internal structure to locate the key in O(log(n)) time.  Whereas `std::find` is a linear search, requiring O(n) time, no matter what container type is used.